# Uses for negative zero floating point value?

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754

Consider the following C++ code:

```
double someZero = 0;
std::cout << 0 - someZero << '\n';   // prints 0
std::cout << -someZero << std::endl; // prints -0
```

The question arises: what is negative zero good for, and should it be defensively avoided (i.e. use subtraction instead of smacking a minus onto a variable)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Answer (score 24):

From Wikipedia:

> It is claimed that the inclusion of signed zero in IEEE 754 makes it much easier to achieve numerical accuracy in some critical problems[1], in particular when computing with complex elementary functions[2].

The first reference is "Branch Cuts for Complex Elementary Functions or Much Ado About Nothing's Sign Bit" by W. Kahan, that is available for download [here](https://people.freebsd.org/~das/kahan86branch.pdf).

One example from that paper is `1/(+0)` vs `1/(-0)`. Here, the sign of zero makes a huge difference, since the first expression equals `+inf` and the second, `-inf`.

Comment: Though that doesn't explain what use signed zero has in a programming language.

Answer (score 3):

In addition 
Signed Zero Good For :

The zeroes can be considered as a variant of the extended real number line such that 1/−0 = −∞ and 1/+0 = +∞, division by zero is only undefined for ±0/±0.

Negatively signed zero echoes the mathematical analysis concept of approaching 0 from below as a one-sided limit, which may be denoted by x → 0−, x → 0−, or x → ↑0. The notation "−0" may be used informally to denote a small negative number that has been rounded to zero. The concept of negative zero also has some theoretical applications in statistical mechanics and other disciplines

Comment: I wonder if it would have been helpful to have three zeros: positive, negative, and unsigned, with subtraction of two negative numbers, or addition of two numbers of opposite sign and equal magnitude, yielding an unsigned zero?  Division by a signed zero should yield infinity, but division by an unsigned zero should yield a NaN.

Comment: Interesting idea. In my opinion, if you introduce unsigned 0, unsigned division by 0 should yield unsigned infinity, and unsigned division of 0/0 should yield unsigned NaN. It would probably be easier to create new types that omit the sign bit, as opposed to mixing in new values that have a sign bit to disregard. Each "unsigned" value still has a sign bit that can flip, so you'd always have a corresponding "negative" copy that needs to represent the same value, compare as equal, etc. Good luck when it comes to -0.0 vs. 0.0 vs. unsigned 0.0, etc.

Comment: Why did you repeat `x → 0−` twice? And why is there the sign after the 0?

Answer (score 1):

There are only two real use-cases that I can see:

1. You want to show that a value is negative but very very small (perhaps infinitessimal), i.e. too small to represent as a float or double.
2. You are working with math that only allows negatives, but still want to display zero. There are a few cases in physics, complex numbers and number theory where this can be useful.

For the mostpart, it's not useful and should be avoided.

You may also want to take a look at this question: [Is there a negative zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199808/is-there-a-negative-zero) and the [IEEE 754 spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) for floating point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a measuring app, and the -0 is very useful for mixed numbers (such as separating into feet and inches).

Imagine that we have a variable "length" that we're trying to separate into "feet" and "inches".

(This is java code, but the same idea is true for C++).

```
feet = Math.signum(length) * Math.floor(Math.abs(length / 12));
// could also do feet = length>0 ? Math.floor(length / 12) : Math.ceil(length / 12)
inches = Math.abs(length) % 12;
```

If the length is between -1 feet and 0 feet, we'd want it to say -0 for the feet so we know it's negative.

Comment: If the length is 0 feet, why would `signum(0)*floor(abs(0))` be -0? That aside, you might be interested in "truncate", it's like floor for positives and ceil for negatives. If you use `truncate(x/12)` and `x/12-truncate(x/12)`, you preserve the sign of x but get integer division and modulo remainder of the magnitude. You also know for certain that `-1 < x-truncate(x) < 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Negative zero has for example some use when handling complex numbers...

In everyday use one should mostly avoid the negative zero.

Some links with information regarding background/uses/pitfalls of "negative zero":

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Signed_zero
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_cut
- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/344366/negative-zero-behavior-between-c-and-c-code-is-different
- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/292276/in-vs2005-c-zero-reported-as-negative-zero-for-double-type
- [C++ ceil and negative zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986875/c-ceil-and-negative-zero)